# Understanding handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#EventCreate').click(function (e) {
            location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "AEvents")';
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="EventCreate" type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="float:right;">Create New Event</button>
```

Now this works perfectly, but my mission is to understand all aspects of why it works.

I have done some reading [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/) but it is not yet settling in my head.  Also, in the reference, all of the examples that are provided don't have a handler.

I have also tried debugging to see what the `e` has/is but have had 0 luck.

My question is why have the `e`?  I know that the `e` is an *event handler* but would this work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (/* no event handler */) {
        $('#EventCreate').click(function (/* no event handler */) {
            location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "AEvents")';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `e` in the above is actually the event object, it gives you some basic information about what triggered the event, such as any keys pressed or mouse position, what the target of the event is.

Comment: I always knew that `e` was a variabele you could pass along to get specific details about the event when it was triggered, but it's not required to pass it along. Only if you plan to do something with the details

Comment: The `e` is **not** an "event handler".  It's the *event object*. The event handler is the function itself. The event object is a jQuery-supplied wrapper around the native event object created by the browser.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/click/ and see what the "e" is.

Comment: @Pointy ahh okay, i got *event handler* from the **Description** in my reference: *Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.* Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e` / `event` / `evt` in that context is actually an [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), **NOT** an event handler. It's the argument that's passed into an event handler/listeners callback function.

This represents the state of that event when it occurred and provides valuable context to the actual event. It is only necessary to inlcude when you require the context data of the event itself. Otherwise it can be omitted, as you can do with most unneeded arguments in JavaScript.

For example, take a simple input handler:

```js
document
  .getElementById('example')
  .addEventListener('change', onChange, false);

function onChange(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value); // value of input
}
```

```html
<label>Example input</label>
<input type="text" id="example" placeholder="Example."/>
```

When you bind a listener to the `change` event, you can access the `e` argument which is an Event Object. With that object, you have the ability to read the current value of the input after was changed.

Answer (score 2):

`e` is the [**event object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) passed to the anonymous callback function.

It is **not mandatory** to explicitly state it in the parameter list, your code will work exactly the same (assuming you aren't trying to reference it).

You could even access it via the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) array (`arguments[0]`) if you wanted, but that would be sloppy in this situation.

The main point is that it will be passed into your function regardless of whether you include it in your function parameters.

Comment: No, `e` is not the "event handler". The event handler is the function. The parameter to the function (`e` in this case)  is the event object.